# Issue with executing files

Tags: linux, file-permissions, execution

I have the following two files:

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 user admin  319 Feb 10 14:23 FileToStart
-rwxrwxrwx 1 user admin 7378 Feb 10 13:37 checkup.sh
```

Now, the "FileToStart" is calling "checkup.sh". If I execute FileToStart while logged in under user, it executes normally.

Now, there is user2. He can execute FileToStart, but, when it comes to the line to call upon checkup.sh, it says that it can not find the mentioned file.

Any suggestions on why is this happening?

Comment: Chances are that `user` has the current directory `.` listed in his `PATH` environment variable, and `user2` doesn't (*`user2` is right, you should not have `.` listed in your `PATH` for security reasons*). Remove it from your `PATH` and execute the second script with `./checkup.sh` instead of plain `checkup.sh`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe these files are in home directory of user and path to checkup.sh in first file looks like "~/checkup.sh"